# Media upload finished hook

Tags: uploads, media-library, thickbox

I'm developing a plugin which uses wordpress's thickbox media library to handle media upload and selection. All is well but for the fact that I would like to automatically 'redirect' to the 'media library'-tab after I uploaded/ wordpress finished crunching the file.

So basically i'm looking for a hook that's fired after the crunching of an uploaded file is finished.

I can't imagine this would be such an extreme thing but I can't seem to find the right hook for this.

Comment: Issue still there... Nobody has an idea?!

Comment: i asked in Trac for the addition of some kind of callback for after the set as featured image link is clicked.  (i got shot down b/c they misunderstood my post as a support request) this is another valid place for a callback to hook into. maybe you could post in Trac as a suggestion too.

Comment: The only way I found is to actively track any changes (jquery) and if, change the layout. I'm quite sure this would be the only way...

Comment: You'd have to, somehow, add an external jQuery listener to this functions: `/wp-includes/js/swfupload/handlers.dev.js`. . . But what if more than one file was dropped in the upload box? What if we drop another one while the previous are still uploading/crunching?

Answer (score 3):

it's a longshot but,

`add_attachment` hook actually fires after the first file finished uploading:

```
add_action('add_attachment','redirect_uploader_flow');
```

I'm using it to load a custom interface for resizing an Image loading in the current TB window:

```
jQuery("#TB_iframeContent",window.parent.document).attr('src',"<?php echo get_window_url($id) ?>");
```

The main problem is that it will break multiple file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

I just check hooks database and find one which could help. It is in https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4-branch/wp-admin/async-upload.php file. It is *upload_files_{$tab}* and it is used near the end of the file.

If I were you I check this hook in my plugin for more information.